# How does concatenation of an empty array prevent mutation with sort?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How does concatenation of an empty array `arr.concat([])` prevent mutation of the initial array?

```
var globalArray = [5, 6, 3, 2, 9];
function nonMutatingSort(arr) {
  return arr.concat([]).sort((a, b) => a - b);
}
nonMutatingSort(globalArray);
```

Comment: Would have been an interesting exercise to try and explain why you thought it would not. I suspect had you done so, you may have come to the correct answer

Comment: Would've been cleaner to write `arr.slice().sort(…)` or `Array.from(arr).sort(…)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.
>
> <sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat</sub>

So, it's a shortcut to create a new array, which basically just contains everything from the original array (plus everything from an empty array, i.e. nothing).